# ImportError: No module named 'ldap' Python 3.5

Tags: python, ldap

I'm running Python 3.5 (on Windows) and I have installed `python-ldap` from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ldap/

I also tried using ldap3 but I keep getting an error saying

`"ImportError: No module named 'ldap'`

I looked around and saw some people saying there's no python-ldap for 3.5 so I installed 2.6 still getting the same error.

Is there a way to import ldap and make it work for Python 3.5?

Comment: how did you install it ? did you try `sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev python-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev` ?

Comment: what is your pip version? do you install by pip3 or pip ?

Comment: I just downloaded the windows installer and followed the instructions

Comment: Hi @VardaElentári, do you install this package in your windows computer?

Comment: @l0o0 yes, I just updated the question

Answer (score 9):

Try the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev python-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev
sudo pip3 install pyldap
```

Comment: the user is asking help on windows os, not debian and derived os.

Answer (score 4):

Open a command line (cmd, powershell, git bash).

Check your Python version:

`$ python --version`

Go to [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

Download the library according to your Python and OS versions, and install it via the command line:

`pip install *file_downloaded.whl*`

For example:
If you have Python 3.5x and Windows x64, you would download **python_ldap‑3.2.0‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl**

`$ pip install python_ldap‑3.2.0‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl`

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Apache Airflow on an Amazon EC2-Instance and I was getting `"ImportError: No module named 'ldap3'`. I used these two sites https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/installing.html and http://ldap3.readthedocs.io/installation.html to run the commands `sudo python -m pip install python-ldap` and `sudo pip install ldap3` but my pip wasn't working for the last command so after some investigation I found out in my `/usr/bin/` directory I had `pip, pip-2.7, pip-3.6, and pip-python` so I changed the command to `pip-3.6 install ldap3` and then everything worked! Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I tried multiple approaches but finally, [PyPI official documentation](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.4.3/installing.html#installing-from-pypi) fixed this.

I was trying to execute on VS Code and did `pip3 install python-ldap`, but it didn't solve the issue. So I did the below from VS Code

```
# %% - This runs the below code as a Jupyter notebook cell
!pip3 install python-ldap
```

Now, I am able to `import ldap` and use it

Answer (score 0):

Inside you folder, you can use virtualenv for python 3, example:

**/opt/python-ldap-test**

**virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.5 venv**

**source venv/bin/activate**

and then

**pip install ldap3**

Answer (score -1):

It's extremely complicated to make things from 2.X to work in 3.X. Have you tried using it in a separate, 2.X only script and using it from there? It's not so unusual to combine python 2.X with 3.X in that manner or so I've heard.